# Loading Keras model error: No Opkernel was registered to support Op 'Assign' with these attrs

Tags: python, tensorflow, raspberry-pi, keras

I've used Floyd hub to to train the following model and saved it

```
# Create the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(3, 32, 32), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu', kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu', kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
# Compile model
epochs = 50
adammax = keras.optimizers.Adamax(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=adammax, metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
```

When I try to load it on my PC, it's working fine. But when I load it on the Raspberry Pi I get the following error. I tried also to save just the weights and load them, but it didn't work and I got the same error. I am using the same version of Tensorflow as Floyd hub on the Raspberry Pi.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi ! You're trying to execute operations with an int64 datatype, but Tensorflow supports only int32 on ARM. (only ARM 32 bits is officially supported.) On the side, please, try to include your Traceback as text instead of an image.

Comment: @Lescurel any recommendations how to port a tensorflow model into Raspberry properly?

Comment: @Paddy : I don't know what you're trying to achieve, but you could simply use tensors with  `tf.int32` datatype instead of `tf.int64`. In a lot of cases, you don't need the extra 32 bits. No idea how to do it with keras or floydhub though. You could also try  to follow this [guide](http://zhiyisun.github.io/2017/02/15/Running-Google-Machine-Learning-Library-Tensorflow-On-ARM-64-bit-Platform.html) on how to compile Tensorflow for ARM64 (Note that I have not tested it)

Comment: @Lescurel : Are you sure this is the problem? Because I didn't get any error when I importing the libraries, building and compiling the model on the Raspberry Pi. I am only getting it when I'm trying to load the weights or the model.

Comment: @AliZuhair : It's what your traceback is showing : you're trying to assign an int64 variable, but the datatype is not supported (the only supported are boolean, int32 and float). It's not related to the building/compiling step. **Your model is using a datatype that the Tensorflow library don't handle on ARM.**

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, you're passing T=DT_INT64, while that is not one of the supported kernels for this op. You could see if the int64 version is just not shipped in the .so file, write the op kernel yourself, or try casting to tf.int32 right before this op in the python code. The last one worked well for me.